# Accessing penitentiary records of Canon City (Colorado) archives

Tags: imprisonment, archives

Summary: my brick wall boils down to three individuals I've found that I'd like to combine into one, but all three are hard to learn anything about. All were born around 1878 according to what little information I have.

Primarily, I've been looking for an inventor and railroad engineer named H. C. Hornback for nine years. He was an obscure individual who lived on trains, in hotels and boarding houses. I haven't found him in any census. I learned about him from a couple of Portland, Oregon newspaper articles from Dec. 1909. He said he'd lived in Colorado from about 1894 to 1909.

In the course of the search I've located parents for a deceased person who was adopted and therefore whose parents were unknown till I found them. His father was named Henry Clay Hornback and he is also hard to find. He died May 3, 1915 in San Francisco, California. He was born about 1878 in Kentucky or Australia (his widow said both back in 1915 according to two different primary documents). Her maiden name was Mary Elizabeth "Bessie" Cullen.

I also think that Clay Hornback of Rocky Ford, Otero County, Colorado is the same person. His father was Solomon Henry Hornback who supposedly came from Nicholas County, Kentucky and who definitely married his wife Eliza P. Edmonston in Mississippi County, Missouri in 1874. I can't find this family anywhere in the 1880 census so I wonder if they were in Australia for a while.

Clay was arrested in 1896 for stealing a bicycle. I found an H. C. Hornback, prisoner number 4084, at the Canon City, Colorado penitentiary but that's all I know about that. Links below describe archived data that may or may not be online at www.colorado.gov. Due to a new Colorado law limiting access to the colorado.gov website, since I live in Asia I can't open the colorado.gov site to see what the procedure is for getting the images if they are not online. The Colorado genealogy site linked below says the images are online or seems to imply it.

I'm an amateur genealogist. I've got 484 files on this family and found nothing on these three men (or two, or one) except a few newspaper articles, city directories from Portland, Oregon, and death report from San Francisco, California. It's at familysearch.org. The Henry Clay Hornback who died in San Francisco was married to Mary Elizabeth "Bessie" Cullen and she is easy to find but he isn't. I have the birth certificate of their child, who is deceased. The two different names he had (due to being adopted) are irrelevant to this discussion as his father died before he was born and he didn't know anything about him except for what was on his birth certificate and he was not raised by his mother.

https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/archives/penitentiary-records is not accessible from where I live in Asia. https://coloradogenealogy.com/history/prisoner-records-available-at-the-colorado-state-archives.htm describes what should be found there.

Comment: Downvoted because the question as it stands right now is so poorly written, it is unclear.  The question could be improved by taking out your lookup request, and stating clearly and explicitly what research question you are trying to answer and what information you would hope to gain from this blocked website if you could view it.  Keep in mind that our community members are already taking time away from their own research to read your question -- making link labels that say "this site" are unfriendly to users who use screen readers or can't read mouse-over text.

Comment: I have looked at the Colorado Archives site and the Archives does not have the prisoner records online. There is a one-page 'sample' flyer with the list of information which *might* be in the record (which is the same information listed on the Colorado Genealogy link).  The only information available to the online researcher is the name and prisoner number from the index which you've already cited in your question.

Comment: @ Jan Murphy, there is no lookup request. I've rewritten the question as per your critique. Your comment does not clarify what a person is supposed to do in order to get the images which I thought were going to be online. "Contact the Colorado archives" as stated on the genealogy site doesn't help me because I can't get on their website and find out how to contact them.

Comment: The records you are seeking are not online; however, you could use search engine to look up the phone number of the archives on line and ask them for instructions to request records by mail (and whether there are any limitations on where they will send such records). No doubt there will be a fee associated with the request.

Comment: There is a "Request a Record" link at the bottom of the page with details on how to request the record...

Comment: @TomH, I suspect that link may not be available where a site prohibits access on geographical grounds. I have become used to gritting my teeth and (surely not) swearing when a site completely/totally/absolutely prevents access from the EU (and maybe other geographies as well.

Comment: You might consider using one of the (many) free VPNs to access the site, and complete the "Request a record" form.

Comment: @ sempaiscuba, Great idea. I tried startpage.com and now able to look at some pages, though not able to do a search. At least this way I can learn what their policies and procedures are.